# Hello. I am having trouble writing form input to a nested json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, next.js

So far I have a Next.js app with a form component that looks like this:

**components/Form.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { mutate } from 'swr'

const Form = ({ formId, demoForm, forNewDemo = true }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const contentType = 'application/json'
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    projectName: demoForm.projectName,
    projectFunction: demoForm.projectFunction,
  })

  /* The PUT method edits an existing entry in the mongodb database. */
  const putData = async (form) => {
    const { id } = router.query

    try {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/demos/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          Accept: contentType,
          'Content-Type': contentType,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(form),
      })

      // Throw error with status code in case Fetch API req failed
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.status)
      }

      const { data } = await res.json()

      mutate(`/api/demos/${id}`, data, false) // Update the local data without a revalidation
      router.push('/')
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage('Failed to update')
    }
  }

  /* The POST method adds a new entry in the mongodb database. */
  const postData = async (form) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/api/demos', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: contentType,
          'Content-Type': contentType,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(form),
      })

      // Throw error with status code in case Fetch API req failed
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.status)
      }

      router.push('/')
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage('')
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target
    const value =
      target.name === 'poddy_trained' ? target.checked : target.value
    const name = target.name

    setForm({
      ...form,
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

  /* Makes sure demo info is filled for demo name, owner name, species, and image url*/
  const formValidate = () => {
    let err = {}
    if (!form.projectFunction) err.projectFunction = 'Function is required'
    return err
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const errs = formValidate()
    if (Object.keys(errs).length === 0) {
      forNewDemo ? postData(form) : putData(form)
    } else {
      setErrors({ errs })
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form id={formId} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea
          name="projectFunction"
          value={form.projectFunction}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          name="projectName"
          value={form.projectName}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {Object.keys(errors).map((err, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{err}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Form
```

the form is located at the /new page

**pages/new.js**

```
import Form from '../components/Form'

const New = () => {
  const demoForm = {
    projectFunction: [],
    projectName: []
  }

  return <Form formId="add-demo-form" demoForm={demoForm} />
}

export default New
```

and here is my api at **pages/api/demos/index.js**

```
import dbConnect from '../../../lib/dbConnect'
import Demo from '../../../models/Demo'
import fs from 'fs'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const {
    method,
    body,
  } = req
  await dbConnect()

  switch (method) {
    case 'POST':
      try {
        const timestamp = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date())));
        const newJsonDirectory = "projects/" + timestamp;
        const newJsonFile = newJsonDirectory + ".json";
        fs.writeFileSync(newJsonFile, JSON.stringify([ "date: " + Date.now().toString(), "name: " +  body.projectName,  "display: projects", "route: "+ newJsonFile]));
        const demo = await Demo.create(
          req.body
        )
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: demo })
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false })
      }
      break
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ success: false })
      break
  }
}
```

lets say I submit my values into the form textarea: **projectFunction**

```bash
function() { 
  echo "hello"
}
```

input: **projectName**

```
hello-world
```

the projects folder would then contain a file that looks like this

**2022-09-10T233306.465Z.json**

and its contents

```json
["date: 1662852786465","name: hello-world","display: projects","route: projects/2022-09-10T23:33:06.465Z.json"]
```

I am relatively new to node.js and have been having difficulty responding with a nested JSON object. I am not sure I am even doing this right... :/ My goal is to return something like this!

```
{
    "order": [
      {
        "name": "hello-world",
        "pages": [
          {
            "display": "projects", 
            "subpages": [
                { "route": "", "display": "projects/2022-09-10T22:53:49.346Z.json" }
            
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

JSON.stringify({ "order": [ { "name": "hello-world", "pages": [{ "display": "projects", "subpages": [{ "route": "", "display": "projects/2022-09-10T22:53:49.346Z.json" }] }]} ] })

instead of

JSON.stringify([ "date: " + Date.now().toString(), "name: " +  body.projectName,  "display: projects", "route: "+ newJsonFile])

also, remove hardcoded strings with variable/function calls